# How to query by creationDate in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cloudkit

I want to fetch the last X minutes of public/private entries from CloudKit.

I tried something in this effect but failed:

```
    let date = NSDate(timeInterval: -60.0 * 120, sinceDate: NSDate())
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "creationDate > %@", date)
```

But this will get me data, but I'm not sure if I'm querying everything or just to some kind of cap:

```
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
```

I want to be able to query by certain amount of time. Is this possible without doing the creation sorting logic on the client side?

Here's the complete code block:

```
func fetchPublicData(completion: ((records:[AnyObject]) -> Void)!)
{
    let date = NSDate(timeInterval: -60.0 * 120, sinceDate: NSDate())
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "creationDate > %@", date)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "MyDataRecordType", predicate: predicate)

    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicDb = container.publicCloudDatabase

    publicDb.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil,
    {
        (results, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            self.handleError(error)
        }
        else
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    })
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: aside: `Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -60 * 120)` is another way to create the date you're using - "120 minutes ago"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**UPDATE 10/5/2020:**

Found out my own question.
You'll need to log in to CloudKit dashboard, go to Schema and make sure "Index Type" is set to queryable.

[image]

Here's more detailed document of what kind of NSPredicate you can use for CloudKit:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckquery#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014043-CH1-SW8

Once setup, you'll be able to query by date like so:

```
let date = NSDate(timeInterval: -60.0 * 120, sinceDate: NSDate())
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "creationDate > %@", date)
```

[DEPRECATED] Screenshot of CloudKit dashboard for first accepted answer below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I promise I won't use this to poll CloudKit on a timer for modificationDate to avoid setting up all those nasty zone callbacks.

Comment: @Genki: I'm afraid with the new CloudKit Dashboard I no longer find how to activate the checkmarks… could you help with a new screenshot?

Comment: @DrMickeyLauer - Thanks for calling that out. I updated it.