# CloudKit query by oldest modified record

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckquery, ckqueryoperation

I am working with CloudKit and attempting to fectch records by "modificationDate" but will populate my results limit starting with the oldest. For instance, if I have 4 records created mon, tues, wed, thurs and I select just two of them, I would get the mon, tues record and not the wed thurs. Below is the code that I am trying to fix.

```
func fetchRecentModified() {

   let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
   let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "votes", ascending: true)
   let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Dog", predicate: predicate)
   query.sortDescriptors = [sort]
   let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
   operation.resultsLimit = recordFetchMax

   operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record) in
       VoteQueue.sharedInstance.append(record)

   }

   operation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) in
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
           if error == nil {
               print("There is no error fetching records \(recordFetchMax)")
               print(VoteQueue.sharedInstance)
               API.shared.flagRecords(VoteQueue.sharedInstance)

           } else {
               print("There was a problem fetching the list of dogs please try again")
               print(error)
           }
       }
   }
   self.database.addOperation(operation)
```

}

I figured it would be as simple as flagging the `NSSortDescriptor` ascending to false. But this did not work (after more testing I found that this will return *only* records that have a value of 0 for a selected field).

Additionally I tried some various predicate comparisons to no avail. Any thoughts? I'm about ready to give up on CloudKit forever.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521999/how-to-query-by-creationdate-in-cloudkit

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26559168/1951992